# Arrow function in event listener for <select><option> (vanilla JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```
 <select name="weeks" id="weeks" multiple>
   <option class="week" name="09" value="09">09</option>
   <option class="week" name="13" value="13">13</option>
   <option class="week" name="14" value="14">14</option>
   <option class="week" name="15" value="15">15</option>
 </select>

for (let option of document.querySelectorAll('option')) {
      //Listen to 'change' event of all options
      option.onchange = (e) => {
        console.log('changed')
      }
 }
```

I would like to add an event listener for each option so that when it is selected something happens. Why is it not working? `option.onselect` also doesn't work.

Comment: `document.getElementById('weeks').addEventListener('change', (event) => {})`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Options don't have `change` events - only `select`s do. Attach a single listener to the `select`.

```js
const select = document.querySelector('#weeks');
select.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  console.log(select.value);
});
```

```html
<select name="weeks" id="weeks">
   <option class="week" name="09" value="09">09</option>
   <option class="week" name="13" value="13">13</option>
   <option class="week" name="14" value="14">14</option>
   <option class="week" name="15" value="15">15</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: or: console.log(e.target.value);